# PHP Variable/Array Value(s) Lower Cased Periodically

Tags: php, windows, utf-8, lowercase, intl

I am currently having an issue with random strings in either variables or array values being lower cased periodically.

Here is an example of what I'm seeing with an array:

```
 $modules = array("Dashboard", "Calendar", "Maintenance", "Service Orders", "Quotes", "Contacts");

var_dump($modules);
```

Output:

```
    array(6) {
      [0]=>
      string(9) "Dashboard"
      [1]=>
      string(8) "Calendar"
      [2]=>
      string(11) "maintenance"
      [3]=>
      string(14) "Service Orders"
      [4]=>
      string(6) "Quotes"
      [5]=>
      string(8) "Contacts"
    }
```

I am doing an `in_array()` condition but it is not finding "Maintenance" due to it being "maintenance".

**EDIT**

Here is an example of what happens with passing a string through a method that tries to get the index in the `$_REQUEST` var:

```
class RequestHandle {

    /**
     * Get the parameter index of the request var
     * @param $index
     * @return string|array
     */
    public static function getParameter($index){
        $value = "";
        $data  = $_REQUEST;

        if(isset($data[$index]) && !is_array($data[$index])) {
            $value = trim($data[$index]);
        } else if(isset($data[$index]) && is_array($data[$index])) {
            foreach($data[$index] as $key => $value){
                $data[$index][$key] = $value;
            }

            $value = $data[$index];
        }

        return $value;
    }
}

$costs = RequestHandle::getParameter("SubLaborCosts");
```

Output:

```
    string(0) ""
```

The Request var is set and with data. When I do a print of `$index` in the `getParameter` method it will display "sublaborcosts", sometimes, and not find the index since "SubLaborCosts" =/= "sublaborcosts". In order for me to correctly grab data without missing anything, I had to modify the method to include:

```
$data  = array_change_key_case($_REQUEST);
$index = strtolower($index);
```

And this is even now and then, 80% of the time it is correct in showing exactly what I have set.

I've never seen this before and here is a list of items that are new to this happening that I think might have an effect... just can't find the solution.

1. UTF-8 charset
2. PHP 5.5
3. intl extension
4. Windows Server 2012

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This happen in arrays created by you? You set `$array[]='Maintenance'` and have 'maintenance'?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I can't believe that PHP would just randomly change the characters that you assigned in a literal array like that. If that really happened, PHP would be practically unusable. There must be something in your application that's doing it.

Comment: @Barmar I have spent many hours this week and last trying to find out why data was not being saving through form posts, but then 2 minutes without touching code, it would save properly.

Comment: If PHP really did this, I'm sure someone would have noticed it before. But I can't find anything in google.

Comment: Can you upload the full code of the script to pastebin.com?

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, I've tried searching and can't find anything. That's why I'm kind of leaning towards it having something to do with the international extension, server, or charset. Maybe something isn't set correctly.

Comment: That was my thought as well. But extensions aren't supposed to change the basic operation of PHP, they just define new built-in functions. If you don't actually call any of the `intl_XXX` functions, I don't see how it could affect it.

Comment: @Barmar For the most part, that is all of the code, especially the array example, but I post more when I get back in my office.

Comment: This seems like something we may not be able to help with here. It's something very peculiar about your configuration.

Comment: @kandrews What happen inside `array_change_key_case()` function?

Comment: @fusion3k that method lower cases the array keys. This was added in after I found this error in order to force all indexes of request to match the passed string, which is also forced to lower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to get this corrected and stable by updating PHP from 5.5.32 to 5.6.18 and using icuxx56 instead of icuxx51 for the intl extension. I don't know if there is a known issue with icuxx51, but it would be something for the PHP devs to look at. Thanks for trying to help guys.

Answer (score 0):

#### About case insensitive in_array():

You can use `preg_grep()` (regular expression):

```
preg_grep( "/Maintenance/i" , $array );
```

The `i` at the end of pattern means 'case insensitive'.

---

- Read more about [preg_grep() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php)
- Read more about [Regular expressions syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php)

Comment: That works for the search, but I'll throw in another example that doesn't deal with arrays.

Comment: @kandrews it works **only** with arrays. To search strings you have to use `preg_match`

Comment: @kandrews or maybe I don't understand. To emulate `in_array` you can call as `count(preg_grep())`

Comment: The array was just an example of something lower casing my values, when it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

@fusion3k's Answer solves the problem, but I'll throw this one in too.

```
function in_array_case_insensitive($needle, $haystack) 
{
    return in_array( strtolower($needle), array_map('strtolower', $haystack) );
}
```

As an aside: Your problem is weird, I've never seen that happen before!